# I am trying to sort the following data frame first in Points, then Wins, and then Cauntry alphabet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

```
#I have tried this code. but Country column should be sorted vice versa!

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Country','Wins','Loses','Draws','Goal_Diff','Points'])
df1=df.sort_values(by=['Points','Wins','Country'],ascending=False)
df1


#sort the following data frame first in Points, then Wins, and then Country (A-Z).
data= [['Iran', 1, 2, 0, -1, 3]
      ,['Spain', 0, 3, 0, -3, 0]
      ,['Portugal', 2, 1, 0, 0, 6]
      ,['Morocco', 3, 0, 0, 4, 9]]
#sort the data frame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['Country','Wins','Loses','Draws','Goal_Diff','Points'])
df
```

Comment: ascending=(False,False,True,..) you can provide multiple boolean value according to columns you provided in by=(col1,col2,col3,....) so it will sort value by col1, then col2 and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
#sort the following data frame first in Points, then Wins, and then Country (A-Z).
data= [['Iran', 1, 2, 0, -1, 3]
      ,['Spain', 0, 3, 0, -3, 0]
      ,['Portugal', 2, 1, 0, 0, 6]
      ,['Morocco', 3, 0, 0, 4, 9]]
#sort the data frame.
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['Country','Wins','Loses','Draws','Goal_Diff','Points'])
df.sort_values(by=['Points','Wins','Country'],ascending=(False,False,True), inplace=True)
df
```

So you can provide multiple boolean values to attribute `ascending=(True, False, ...)`